# Twig (in Symfony) : access template parameters from twig extensions

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I would like to access Twig template parameters from my twig extensions (filters, functions...) without passing it explicitly.

I always need a "displayPreferences" variable in all my twig extensions, in order to change the way to display and transform values.

It is possible to pass this variable as a template parameter, and pass it as an argument for each Twig filters / functions I run, but that makes the templates difficult to read.

Something like that would be great:

```
/**
 * Twig filter (render a date using the user defined format)
 *
 * @param Date $date
 */
public function renderUserDate ($date) {
    // Somehow, get a template parameter, without receiving it as argument
    $renderPreference = $this->accessTemplateParameter('displayPreferences');

    switch ($renderPreference['dateFormat']) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define a [Context-aware Filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#context-aware-filters):

> If you want to access the current context in your filter, set the
>   needs_context option to true; Twig will pass the current context as
>   the first argument to the filter call (or the second one if
>   needs_environment is also set to true):

The context that is passed  includes variables defined in the template.

So change the definition of the filter adding the required need_context parameters:

```
public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'renderUserDate', ,array('needs_context' => true)),
        );
    }
```

an then use as example:

```
/**
 * Twig filter (render a date using the user defined format)
 *
 * @param array $context: injected by twig
 * @param Date $date
 */
public function renderUserDate ($context, $date) {
    // defined in the template
    $renderPreference = $context['displayPreferences'];

    switch ($renderPreference['dateFormat']) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being able to define context aware filters that let you reference template variables as noted in the accepted answer, you can also define context aware functions. The [twig documentation on functions](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#functions) mentions this:

> Functions support the same features as filters, except for the
>   pre_escape and preserves_safety options.

Also, if you take a look at [twig's code for functions](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Function.php) it shows 'needs_context' as one of the available options.

Here is an example of a function that takes a passed value if supplied during the function call or uses the value from a context variable (template variable) if not:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('photobox', function($context, $page = false) {
            $page = $page ? $page : $context['page'];
            return $this->app['helper.theme']->photobox($page);
        }, array('needs_context' => true))
    );
}
```

Another quick tip that helped me when working with the context: if you want to see what variables are present in the context for you to reference in your twig function or filter simply reference twig's [dump function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) `{{ dump() }}` in you template.